# MySQL find matching set of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cross-reference table that supplies the many-to-many relationship between users and user group tables.  It contains two relevant columns: `group_id` and `user_id` (surprise, surprise!).  When a user wants to create a new group, I want to first check if that set of users already exists as a group.
**Essentially I would define the problem as** "Given a set of user ids, find any set of rows that match the set of user ids and all share the same group id".

**Edit**:

I'm looking for the exact set of users, not interesting in seeing in the resultset groups that include those users in addition to other users.

**Sample Data**

[image: sample data]

I have the hunch that a subquery is the way to go, but I can't figure out how to arrange it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: please add some sample data, expected output and your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select groupid
from usergroups ug
where userid in ($user1, $user2, . . . , $usern)
group by groupid
having count(*) = <n>;
```

This returns all groups that have the supplied list of users.

If you want the *exact* set, then:

```
select groupid
from usergroups ug
group by groupid
having count(*) = sum( userid in ($user1, $user2, . . . , $usern) );
```

This assumes that groups don't have the same user twice (it is not hard to adjust for that, but the condition becomes more complicated).

Comment: probably `count(*) >= <n>` (OP didn't say *only* certain users)

Comment: @Bohemian . . . The `where` restricts the possible users only to the list supplied.  Hence the `=`.

Comment: @Bohemian I may not have specified, but I actually do need to find the exact set.  And that's the only thing missing from this answer.  Gordon, is there a way to accomplish just that - to make sure the group doesn't include any other users, either?

Comment: I never knew you could do `sum(x in (1,2,3))` in SQL!

Comment: @ygesher . . . It works in MySQL.  Something similar works in Postgres.  It is not standard SQL, but I find it convenient.